# Error en NodeJS typings message Unable to find "–global" ("npm") in the registry

Tags: nodejs, typings

Me da el siguiente error en **NodeJS**:

```
ypings ERR! message Unable to find "–global" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to the registry: sshttps:/./github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/%E2%80%93global/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200
typings ERR! 
typings ERR! cwd /Users/batman/desa2017/nodejs/batimovil
typings ERR! system Darwin 16.1.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "–global"
typings ERR! node -v v6.9.1
typings ERR! typings -v 2.1.0
typings ERR! 
typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>

npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/6.9.1/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "typings" "--" "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "–global"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v4.2.0
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ typings: `typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "–global"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ typings script 'typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "–global"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the  package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     typings "install" "dt~core-js" "--save" "–global"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs 
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls 
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con

```
typings install env~node --global
```

Ese mensaje no es muy amistoso y no da ninguna pista de cómo solucionarlo. Un usuario [creó un issue](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/652) por este tema quejándose de lo críptico que es el error.